# Designating single cell value if it matches any in secondary column in R

Tags: r

I am currently trying to designate appointments at general pratice clinics into either GP and other healthcare provider. I want to create a new column for this and do the following

1. If previous column states that its GP appointment, put `GP` in new column
2. If previous column states that its other HCP appointment, put `Other HCP` in new column
3. If it has a blank entry in previous column, then look at list in a second `data.frame` containing known GP appointments. If it matches any entry in that column, designate as `GP`
4. If it has a blank entry in previous column, then look at list in a second `data.frame` containing known Other HCP appointments. If it matches any entry in that column, designate as `Other HCP`

I tried to do that this way. Please note, `appts` is the `data.frame` I want to put the `GP` or `other HCP` into, and `gp appts` and `ohcp appts` are the lists of appointments that lets me designate if the entries are blank to begin with

```
appts$hcpdesignation <-NA

appts$hcpdesignation [appts$hcpcat == "GP"] <- "GP"

appts$hcpdesignation [appts$hcpcat == "Other HCP"] <- "Other HCP"

appts$hcpdesignation [appts$V11 == "" & appts$V10 == gpappts$apptype] <- "GP"

appts$hcpdesignation [appts$V11 == "" & appts$V10 == ohcpappts$apptype] <- "Other HCP"
```

I guess the part that's wrong is the `appts$V10 == ohcpappts$apptype`, but I don't know otherwise how to say "if this single entry matches any of the entries in this column"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1:** I think you're looking for the [`%in%`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) operator.

**2:** I'm not sure why you're testing column `hcpcat` in the first two tests, and then `V11` in the second two tests. Your stepwise instructions say to test the "previous column" for all 4 tests. I assumed that was a mistake.

```
## generate data
set.seed(2L);
div <- sample(c(T,F),10L,T);
N <- 20L;
gpappts <- data.frame(apptype=letters[1:10][div],stringsAsFactors=F);
ohcpappts <- data.frame(apptype=letters[1:10][!div],stringsAsFactors=F);
appts <- data.frame(hcpcat=sample(c('GP','Other HCP',''),N,T),V10=sample(letters[1:12],N,T),stringsAsFactors=F);
```

---

```
## solution
appts$hcpdesignation <- NA;
appts$hcpdesignation[appts$hcpcat=='GP'] <- 'GP';
appts$hcpdesignation[appts$hcpcat=='Other HCP'] <- 'Other HCP';
appts$hcpdesignation[appts$hcpcat=='' & appts$V10%in%gpappts$apptype] <- 'GP';
appts$hcpdesignation[appts$hcpcat=='' & appts$V10%in%ohcpappts$apptype] <- 'Other HCP';
```

---

```
## results
gpappts;
##   apptype
## 1       a
## 2       d
## 3       g
## 4       i
ohcpappts;
##   apptype
## 1       b
## 2       c
## 3       e
## 4       f
## 5       h
## 6       j
appts;
##       hcpcat V10 hcpdesignation
## 1  Other HCP   a      Other HCP
## 2         GP   b             GP
## 3              j      Other HCP
## 4         GP   k             GP
## 5  Other HCP   g      Other HCP
## 6              h      Other HCP
## 7              k           <NA>
## 8         GP   d             GP
## 9  Other HCP   i      Other HCP
## 10        GP   b             GP
## 11 Other HCP   l      Other HCP
## 12 Other HCP   d      Other HCP
## 13             b      Other HCP
## 14        GP   b             GP
## 15 Other HCP   l      Other HCP
## 16 Other HCP   j      Other HCP
## 17        GP   l             GP
## 18 Other HCP   e      Other HCP
## 19             g             GP
## 20        GP   j             GP
```